# Java tutorial for C# developer

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to really grok Java for a C# guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90578/best-way-to-really-grok-java-for-a-c-guy)

I worked on C# for a few years now move to Java. Is there a good Java tutorial for C# developers?

thanks!

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570850/-net-guy-getting-up-to-speed-on-java-suggested-resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a helpful article](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html) to compare the language syntax and some differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know java has a similar syntax ;

anyway have a look [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/codesharp/java-for-c-developers-21248) this article compare c# and java keywords

Answer (score 0):

This book isn't geared specifically towards people coming from a C# background, but I still recommend it highly.   You'll draw the comparisons with C# on your own as you read.  And it is free in electronic form.  [Bruce Eckel's "Thinking In Java"](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)